# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable (new beginner)

Tags: python, python-2.x

This is my Task:
Require the user to enter their name, with only a certain name being able to trigger the loop.
Print out the number of tries it took the user before inputting the correct number.
Add a conditional statement that will cause the user to exit the program without giving the average of the numbers entered if they enter a certain input

```
numbers = []
number = 0

count = 0
total = 0
name = 0

while number >= 0:
    number = int(raw_input("Please enter any number: \n"))
    if number == -1:
        break
    numbers.append(number)

avg = float(sum(numbers)) / len(numbers)
print "The average of the numbers you entered is " + str(avg) + "!"

while name >= 0:
    name = int(raw_input("Please enter the number of characters your name contains: \n"))
    count += 1
    total += count
    if name == 6:
        break

tries = sum(total)
print tries
```

Comment: And what's your problem? Is something not working? If so, whats makes you think this is not working?

Comment: always add in question FULL error message (Traceback) . There are other usefull information.

Comment: If I run it it says the Type Error 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: it is NOT FULL error message (Traceback) - and add it to question. Full message shows ie. which line makes problem, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`tries = sum(total)`... `sum` takes an iterable whereas total is an `int` hence the error.

Comment: What do I have to do to fix it? @Pythonista

Answer (score 0):

If **total = [ ]**
and you can append count values in total that would be fine.

so total.append(count)

would create list then you can use **sum(total)** on it

but here you can simply use print total or count both are same.

```
numbers = []
number = 0

count = 0
total = 0
name = 0

while number >= 0:
    number = int(raw_input("Please enter any number: \n"))
    if number == -1:
        break
    numbers.append(number)

avg = float(sum(numbers)) / len(numbers)
print "The average of the numbers you entered is " + str(avg) + "!"

while name >= 0:
    name = int(raw_input("Please enter the number of characters your name contains: \n"))
    count += 1
    total += count
    if name == 6:
        break

tries = total
print tries
```

and you try to reduce your code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!